# parsing the value in between two XML tags

Tags: c, linux, parsing, tags

I know this one has been asked before, however I can't seem to find a suitable solution, so I 'll state the problem:

I have a string of characters that is similar to an XML file. It's not an XML string, but it has opening and closing tags. All the information resides in one single line, for example:

```
<user>username</username>random data;some more random data<another tag>data</anothertag>randomdata;<mydata>myinfo</mydata>some more random data....
```

etc...

I am trying to read ONLY what's in between `<mydata></mydata>`. Any way to just parse this?

thanks, code is appreciated.

Comment: So the input string is not valid XML?

Comment: Yeah, was going to say, why not just make it valid XML, then you have parsers & encoders at your fingertips.

Comment: no, as I mentioned, it's NOT an XML string.

Comment: @Shawn D. Because I am not in charge of that string. I just get it and need to parse it. I can't force my customer to create a valid XML string when they don't need to. Besides, bringing a full XML parser just to parse one single tag is a huge overkill. thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use strstr():

```
char * get_value(const char *input)
{
  const char *start, *end;

  if((start = strstr(input, "<mydata>")) != NULL)
  {
    start += strlen("<mydata>");
    if((end = strstr(start, "</mydata>")) != NULL)
    {
      char *out = malloc(end - start + 1);
      if(out != NULL)
      {
        memcpy(out, start, (end - start));
        out[end - start] = '\0';
        return out;
      }
    }
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Note that the above is untested, written directly into the SO edit box. So, it's almost guaranteed to contain at least one off-by-one error.

Comment: thanks. the code only returns the 1st 12 characters of the string. I can't figure out why.

Comment: hmmm... sometimes the string passed onto input contains a carriage return even though it is part of the same buffer (string). However I see how this affects strstr() into returning only the 1st 12 characters...

Comment: it has to do with the memcpy. I just added a for loop and copy each char of start into out until i < end - start and it works.

Comment: @Jessica: `memcpy()` isn't affected by carriage returns.

Comment: @Jessica: You found a bug, the second argument to memcpy() was incorrect. It's fixed now.