# Extract data between two delimiters

Tags: c, delimiter, string-parsing

I just want to know whether it is possible to pick up the data that is present between two delimiters (delimiter being a string).

For example the original string is as under

```
<message%20type%3D"info"%20code%3D"20005">%20<text>Conference%20successfully%20modified</text>%20<data>0117246</data>%20%20</message>%20
```

and I want the data that is present between `<text>` tags. The string from which i need the data can be different. The string can also be like this

```
<message%20type%3D"info"%20code%3D"20001">%20<text>Conference%20deleted</text%20%20<vanity>0116976</vanity>%20</message>%20<message%20type%3D"info"%20code%3D"20002">%20<text>Number%20of%20conferences%20deleted</text>%20<data>1</data>%20%20</message>%20
```

but I always need the data present between the `<text>` tags.

So is it possible in C language or is there any alternative?

Comment: possible duplicate of [parsing the value in between two XML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493714/parsing-the-value-in-between-two-xml-tags)

Comment: Is the malformed close tag `</text` in the second example intentional and representative?

Comment: I see your question has changed completely .. Please don't change the question..so that makes the answer look wrong

Comment: @Gopi I have not changed the question.

Comment: I mean the string shown was different when you posted initially it didn't had `<message......`

Comment: @tripleee It is a similar to parsing the value in between two XML tags but the difference is that in this case there could be multiple <text> tags so the solution given in parsing the value in between two XML tags won't work

Comment: @Gopi I fixed the formatting so you're right that the tag wasn't originally *visible* but it was there all along.  The StackOverflow markup really sucks in that unsupported tags in body text simply disappear.

Comment: XML can certainly contain multiple occurrences of the same tag in the same document or even on the same line.

Comment: @tripleee That malformed close tag that you are talking of is actually </text>. I think it got left out while i was copying the string. So in a nut shell the close tag is </text> not </text

Comment: I need to escape the double quotes in my string. Is there a way to escape it dynamically

Answer (score 7):

I'd go with [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html).

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char data[] = "<message%20type%3D\"info\"%20code"
                  "%3D\"20005\">%20<text>Conference%"
                  "20successfully%20modified</text>%"
                  "20<data>0117246</data>%20%20</mes"
                  "sage>%20";
    char *p1, *p2;
    p1 = strstr(data, "<text>");
    if (p1) {
        p2 = strstr(p1, "</text>");
        if (p2) printf("%.*s\n", p2 - p1 - 6, p1 + 6);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are functions `strtok()` and `strtok_r()` which can be used to extract the data based on the delimiters.

```
char a[100] = "%20Conference%20successfully%20modified%200117246%20%20%20";
char *p = strtok(a,"%");
while(p != NULL)
{
  // Save the value in pointer p
  p = strtok(NULL,"%");
}
```

If you want the string `a` to be unmodified then have a separate array `b`
`char b[100]` and copy the string to `b`

```
strcpy(b,a);
```

Code and output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char a[100] = "%20Conference%20successfully%20modified%200117246%20%20%20";
    char *p = strtok(a,"%");
    char n[20];
    while(p != NULL)
    {
      strcpy(n,p);
      p = strtok(NULL,"%");
      printf("%s\n",n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
20Conference
20successfully
20modified
200117246
20
20
20
```

PS: `strtok()` modifies the passed string.Check man
http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r

Comment: "I always need the data present between the `<text>` tag" You're solving a different problem.

Comment: @weston I have added a `PS` please check it.. If that is the case then the initial string needs to be saved and the string which is passed to strotk() should be a different one ..How am I solving some other issue this is the solution OP wants just an addition is that the initial string shouldn't be changed

Comment: OP wants to extract the text in between the tags but your example starts with what they want to end with then breaks it up by `%`.

Comment: Oh, I did not realize question was changed. That explains it.